# Properly decode Get Blob data string to ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, jquery, binary, azure-storage

I have the following code that [receives blob's data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179440.aspx) from Azure Storage:

```
$.ajax({
        headers: {
            'x-ms-range': 'bytes=' + from + '-' + to,
            'x-ms-version': '2015-07-08',
            'x-ms-client-request-id': guid()
        },
        url: uri,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            /* data is a string! */
        },
        error: function (error, textStatus) { }
});
```

The call works fine and I receive the data in a textual form.
The problem is that I need to convert it to an `ArrayBuffer`.

Now I've tried lots of ways, such as:

```
new TextEncoder().encode(data);
```

and the following converter:

```
function stringToUint(string) {
    var charList = string.split(''),
    uintArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < charList.length; i++) {
        uintArray.push(charList[i].charCodeAt(0));
    }
    return new Uint16Array(uintArray);
}
```

But the data string isn't converted properly to binary (I've checked against the real binary value of the blob).

Should I use a different `ArrayBuffer` type? or am I using the wrong encoding (I've tried utf-8, utf-16, utf-32) when converting with the TextEncoder?

Please help :(

Comment: Is it helping? http://blog.danguer.com/2011/10/24/base64-binary-decoding-in-javascript/

Comment: It's not encoded in base64... It's as if you opened a binary file with a text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What finally worked for me was to use this [jquery extension](https://github.com/henrya/js-jquery/tree/master/BinaryTransport)
and change the request to:

```
$.ajax({
        headers: {
            'x-ms-range': 'bytes=' + from + '-' + to,
            'x-ms-version': '2015-07-08',
            'x-ms-client-request-id': guid()
        },
        url: uri,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'binary',
        responseType:'arraybuffer',
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            /* data is an arraybuffer! */
        },
        error: function (error, textStatus) { }
});
```

Hopefully, it will help other people as well...